# Use Salesforce account for credential check

Tags: api, php, login

How do I use Salesforce account to validate login without security token? 
I have a requirement to use Salesforce account as authentication to access certain internal pages(another website). On a login screen, the user enters his/her SF login information(username and password) without token and then using SFDC PHP API to authenticate if the user account is valid. If valid, provide access to those pages. 
Can I use SF PHP API for this purpose?
Since the internal website is hosted on a server, can I use that server IP on Salesforce whitelist ip to avoid asking for token?

Comment: Google must be broken today. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_IdP_Setup

Comment: Thanks Eric! We have the SAML enabled and we are using it. Is there a way for a external users to login with API?